# Rails Paperclip images when window resize cause reload data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, paperclip

I am using rails 4.2.1 and paperclip 4.2 for upload images, with datatables images show up in datatable

in my model:

```
def call_image
   self.files.first.try(:image_url, :thumb)
end
```

and in my index.html i call images for each user for example avatars

```
image_tag(user.avatars.call_image)
```

everything works fine but just i have wondered 
when i am on my index page and try to resize browser window my console records shows (on development mode) that all images reloading data again when i try everytime resize the window

there is any way to stop reloading all data over again when i resize window cause of images or it is normal thing or my code can be wrong?

Thanks

Edit: also i am using datatables and images in datatable , when i take out images from table there is no issue with reload just when i put them in the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : [datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth](http://Solution%20:%20datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth%20make%20it%20false%20to%20prevent%20reload%20images%20when%20resize%20window) make it false to prevent reload images when resize window